# Can't Able To Find MySQL Config File After Upgrade

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I am using MySQL on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Since I upgraded MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8 on my machine, i can't find where config file is.

After upgrade, i just head over to /etc/mysql directory on on here i found;

```
--> conf.d (folder)
--> mysql.conf.d (folder)
--> my.cnf (file)
--> mysql.cnf (file)
--> my.cnf.fallback
```

I look my.cnf, my.cnf.fallback and mysql.cnf files. And in all these filese, these lines were written;

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

So first I looked on conf.d folder. Inside of it, there is two files. mysql.cnf and mysqldump.cnf I just skipped mysqldump and looked mysql.cnf. But it just writes;

```
[mysql]
```

So I went to mysql.conf.d file. Inside of it, these are the files;

```
default-auth-override.cnf
mysqld.cnf
mysqld.cnd.dpkg-old
mysqld.cnf.save
mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
```

I just used cat command to look all of these files and just find the mysql configuration I am used to on these files;

```
mysqld.cnf.dpkg-old
mysqld.cnf.save
```

So first I tried changing values on these files, but nothing changed. Then I backup up everything and deleted these two config files and restarted MySQL. Everything still working fine :/

I used;

```
mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1
```

command to find where config file can be.

Output was;

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Looked these directories but found nothing.

I am running server without finding config file more than a month. I don't want to just make clean installation of everything because it is a remote database server and so much thing going on on it.

This is my first question on this website and English is not my native language so please forgive me.

Update 1: I try to find MySQL config files by searching the terms which is included in config file. All the ones system found has no effect on MySQL. Very interesting..